# Is a Windows OS license needed for a reserved Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

If I spin up a pay-as-you-go VM with Windows Server/10, then the license is included in the price.

But if I buy a reserved VM, would I then need to buy a normal license for either Windows Server or Windows 10 in addition to the cost for the reserved VM?

https://portal.azure.com/?l=en.en-us#create/Microsoft.Reservations

I see this when filling out the create reserved VM page. (As I am doing this for a volunteer organisation, I need to make sure that I know what the costs are to avoid any surprises.)

[image]

I did find a link about Software costs but I don't understand how to calculate software meters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/billing/billing-reserved-instance-windows-software-costs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the azure documentation the reservation discounts are for the infrastructure only. You are charged for windows and other software. If you have the azure hybrid benefit then you get the windows charges covered . 
Check the table for the row "Windows VMs with additional software "

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-understand-vm-reservation-charges

Comment: Thank you for a swift reply. 
Let me rephrase the above a bit. Can I use any license that i currently have in my possession for this or am I required to use a specific Azure license?
Let's say that I have an old Windows 10 license that is no longer being used, can I install Windows 10 on the VM and use that license?

Comment: You can bring your windows 10 to azure with multi tenant hosting rights. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/windows-desktop-multitenant-hosting-deployment also Please check the azure hybrid benefit faq https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/hybrid-benefit/faq/